# DropdownMenu rerenders all dropdownitems on every click

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

**Environment**

- React 16.0.0
- Reactstrap 5.0.0

**Situation**

I am using the component `UncontrolledDropdown --> DropdownToggle --> DropdownMenu --> DropdownItem`. For the `DropdownItem` I need to pass it a function so that it changes its father's state (which is its own prop value). This is because I want the `DropdownToggle` element to show the value of the selected `DropdownItem`. For that to happen, the father component holds the value of the selected `DopdownItem`, and it is passed to `DropdownToggle` as a prop.

I have done that in two different ways but both end up in the same situation. Whenever I click one of the `DropdownItem` from the dropdown , they all get re rendered and I can't understand why. Mind you, the list is of over 500 `DropdownItems` and re rendering gives it a teeny bit of lag.

**Code**

**Option A**

```
export default class Father extends React.Component {
    ...
getDropdown = () => {
        const dropdownItems = this.state.retailers.map(retailer => {
            console.log("rendering");
            return <Di key={retailer} retailer={retailer} active={false} itemClick={this.setRetailer} />
        });
        return (
            <UncontrolledDropdown size="lg" className="dropdown-pim">
                <DropdownToggle tag="h3" className="dropdowntoggle-pim text-left" caret={false}>
                    {this.state.retailer} <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu className="rounded">
                    {dropdownItems}
                </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
        );
    }

}

class Di extends React.Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.itemClick(this.props.retailer);
    }

    render() {
        return (<DropdownItem onClick={this.handleClick}
                              active={this.props.active}
                              className="btn-pim rounded">
            {this.props.retailer}
        </DropdownItem>);
    }
}
```

One of the reasons why I did it like this is to avoid having to create multiple arrow functions to be able to pass "handleClick" a value. Which is what I end up doing in option B.

**Option B**

```
getDropdown = () => {
        const dropdownItems = this.state.retailers.map(retailer => {
            console.log("rendering");
            return (<DropdownItem onClick={() => {this.setRetailer(retailer)}}
                                  active={false}
                                  className="btn-pim rounded"
                                    key={retailer}>
                    {retailer}
                    </DropdownItem>);
        });
        return (
            <UncontrolledDropdown size="lg" className="dropdown-pim">
                <DropdownToggle tag="h3" className="dropdowntoggle-pim text-left" caret={false}>
                    {this.state.retailer} <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu className="rounded">
                    {dropdownItems}
                </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
        );
    }
```

---

On both coding options the "rendering" message comes up once, which is good, the first time, but then whenever I click one of the `Di`s, it gets all re rendered again. Is that what's supposed to happen? I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Changing state (via passed handler) in parent results in parent rerendering (by design). You can avoid this by `shouldComponentUpdate`.